# JavaScript - Making generic map/find/filter function

Tags: javascript, arrays

**TLDR;**
How would you go about making a function that e.g. search for value e.g. in array, but where the property searched for can change?

Example.

```js
    const search = (arr, text) =>
    {
        // What if rather than e.name we wanted to search on e.phone?
        // And how could this be passed with the function params?
        return arr.find(e => e.name === text)
    }
```

Comment: You can use bracket notation to access any property. See here: [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896)

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea that was even a thing. Thank a lot man :)

Comment: Add another parameter `(arr, prop, text)` and use `e[prop] === text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` to find a nested property (passed in as a string) to compare with the text.

```js
const search = (arr, prop, text) =>{
  const getProp = obj => prop.split('.').reduce((acc,curr)=>acc?.[curr], obj);
  return arr.find(e => getProp(e) === text);
}
console.log(search([{a: 1}, {a: {b: 'test'}}], 'a.b', 'test'));
console.log(search([{name: 'Joe'}, {name: 'John'}, {name: 'Bob'}], 'name', 'Bob'));
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for a way to make a filter function that is not associated with only 1 key in object

Comment: @Rajesh Are they not looking for a way to search a dynamic property?

Comment: @Rajesh - I was yes, OrAssayag posted the solution.

Comment: I support this anwer . Simple and short.